# Convert RGB to RGBA at 0.9 alpha in string

Tags: string, gradient, str-replace, alpha, rgba

I need to take the color gradient and dynamically change rgb to rgba and add 0.9 alpha, or some other number. Of course div id="gradient" can have more than three rgb and rgba colors. I tried replace ((')', ', 0.9)'). Replace ('rgb', 'rgba'); but it does not work.  How do I do this?

The result should look like:

linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(205, 55, 55, 0.7) 11%, **rgba**(80, 55, 205, **0.9**) 45%, rgba(55, 205, 73, 0.5) 79%)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var gradient = document.getElementById("gradient").style.background;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gradient.replace(')', ', 0.9)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient" style="background: linear-gradient(
90deg
, rgba(215, 45, 45, 0.7) 11%, rgb(73, 45, 215) 45%, rgba(45, 215, 65, 0.5) 79%);"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace directly in the style, you could use the code below. However, if possible, you should instead have the different styles in a css file then just switch the whole element style (ex. `gradient-idle` to `gradient-clicked` or whatever your needs are) on click.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var gradient = document.getElementById("gradient")
        .style
        .background
        .replace(/rgb\([0-9]{1,3},\s[0-9]{1,3},\s[0-9]{1,3}/, "$&, 0.75") // put another alpha here instead of 0.75
        .replace("rgb(", "rgba("); // then replace rgb( with rgba(

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gradient;
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = gradient;
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient" style="
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,
    rgba(205, 55, 55, 0.7) 11%,
    rgb(80, 55, 205) 45%,
    rgba(55, 205, 73, 0.5) 79%);"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also be:

```js
// a regular expression with named capturing group "rgb" that captures the RGB values: "rgb(1, 20, 140)" -> "1, 20, 140"
const r = /rgb\((?<rgb>\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+)\)/;

let style = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(205, 55, 55) 11%, rgb(80, 55, 205) 45%, rgb(55, 205, 73) 79%)';

// now we can change the values 1 by 1

style = style.replace(r, "rgba($1, 0.7)");
// linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(205, 55, 55, 0.7) 11%, rgb(80, 55, 205) 45%, rgb(55, 205, 73) 79%)

style = style.replace(r, "rgba($1, 0.9)");
// linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(205, 55, 55, 0.7) 11%, rgba(80, 55, 205, 0.9) 45%, rgb(55, 205, 73) 79%)

style = style.replace(r, "rgba($1, 0.5)");
// linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(205, 55, 55, 0.7) 11%, rgba(80, 55, 205, 0.9) 45%, rgba(55, 205, 73, 0.5) 79%)

console.log(style);

// linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(205, 55, 55, 0.7) 11%, rgba(80, 55, 205, 0.9) 45%, rgba(55, 205, 73, 0.5) 79%)
```